# If a matrix multiplied by its transpose equals the original matrix, is it symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the question:

> Prove: If A<sup>T</sup>A = A, then A is symmetric and A = A<sup>2</sup>

I tried to solve this by using inference.

> 1. Assume A is symmetric, prove A = A<sup>2</sup>
>
>    - If A is symmetric, then by definition A<sup>T</sup>A = A<sup>2</sup>. Since A<sup>T</sup>A = A, then A = A<sup>2</sup>.
> 2. Assume A = A<sup>2</sup>, prove A is symmetric
>
>    - ??

I wasn't sure what to put for the second part to prove 1. Is an idempotent matrix by definition symmetric? It would make sense, but I couldn't find anything definitive.

Am I going about this correctly, or should I take a different approach?

Comment: HINT Prove that for any matrix $X$, the matrix $X^T X$ is symmetric.

Comment: $A$ being symmetric is not equivalent to $A=A^2$. And even if you tried proving the two desired conclusions are equivalent it wouldn't be the same as proving they both follow from $A^TA=A$. I would evaluate this by going directly to subscript notation and looking at the components individually - then all you need is commutativity in scalars.

Comment: $[A^TA]^T=AA^T$

Comment: @user9352: No, that's not correct in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what you need to prove. You seem to be attempting to prove that

> **If** $A^TA$, **then** ($A$ is symmetric **if and only if** $A=A^2$).

But that is not what you are being asked to prove! What you are being asked to prove is that

> **If** $A^TA=A$, **then** ($A$ is symmetric **and** $A=A^2$).

So you are not allowed to just *assume* that $A$ is symmetric or that $A=A^2$; you need to prove these things from *only* the hypothesis that $A^TA=A$.

Your *only* assumption is that $A^TA=A$.

1. To prove $A$ is symmetric, remember that $A$ is symmetric if and only if $A^T=A$. But if $A=A^TA$, then $A^T = (A^TA)^T = \cdots$
2. To prove that $A=A^2$, argue like you did above, since you have now shown that $A$ is symmetric.

Note that in general, the two statements I wrote above in the grey boxes are not logically equivalent. If the second one holds, then the first one must (because both sides of the "if and only if" will be true whenever the premise is true); but you can have the former one be true and the latter one not be true. For example, "if $x$ is a real number, then ($x$ is positive if and only if $-x$ is negative)" is true, but "if $x$ is a real number, then ($x$ is positive *and* $-x$ is negative)" is false (as witnessed by $x=-1$).

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I am really weak at proofs because I often take the wrong approach. I didn't even think of applying the transpose to both sides (I thought of multiplying both sides by A^-1, but A wasn't stated as being invertible in the question).

Comment: @tjameson: Far more important than how to prove this particular statement is that you realize and recognize the difference between what you were attempting to prove and what you were *supposed* to prove. That is: what you were trying to prove was *different* from what you were supposed to be trying to prove, and that is a much more serious issue than being stuck on this particular problem.